# Avoid flicker on load / custom jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, flicker

I´m using some jQuery to make tabs on a page. My problem is that if you are on a somewhat bad connection, the areas that are hidden by the script flickers and shows before going into hiding.

If someone could help me modify this script to avoid this I would be very grateful, it looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
// For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
// which tab is active and it's associated content
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

// Use the first link as the initial active tab
$active = $links.first().addClass('active');
$content = $($active.attr('href'));

// Hide the remaining content
$links.not(':first').each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
});

  // Bind the click event handler
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();

    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
});
```

Comment: why don't you use `display:none;` property of css? later show/hide the elements using jQ.

Comment: I´m not to comfortable with jQuery. You mean, set the initial display in my css to none, and then then the dom has loaded, set it to normal? Then just let this script do its thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ul.tabs {display:none}
```

And show it on ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $('ul.tabs').show()}
```

Comment: ul.tabs are the list/menu to show/hide the tabbed areas. I added a class of "tabbed" to my tabbed areas, and used your code on those instead and that worked. So thanks!